# insert many to many SonataAdmin Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many, sonata-admin

I have two tables, one called Portal and another called Categories, these are joined by a link table, because the relationship is many to many.
The code tables are as follows:

**Class Categories**

```
/**
* @var integer
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
**/
private $id;

 /**
* @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Portal")
*/ 
 private $portal;

public function __construct() {
 $this->portal = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}    
    ...
```

> **Class Portal**

```
class Portal
{
/**
* @var integer
*
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")     
*/

private $id;


/**
* @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categories")
* @JoinTable(name="portal_categories")
*/
private $categories;


   public function __construct() {
    $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
  }
....
```

And I developed the following 
in **PortalAdmin::configureFormFields**

```
$formMapper
         ->with('Portal')   
         ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => ' Name'))
         ->add('description', 'text', array('label' => 'Description'))
         ->add('webSiteLink', 'text', array('label' => 'Web Site ','required'=> false))           
         ->add('categories', 'sonata_type_collection',array( 'by_reference' => false))
     ->end();
```

But, only appear a button with a popup for insert a new category, but I need, that only appear a list with categories and add any number of categories

When I try with this:

```
$formMapper
           ->with('Portal')   
                ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => ' Name'))
                ->add('description', 'text', array('label' => 'Description'))
                ->add('webSiteLink', 'text', array('label' => 'Web Site ','required'=> false))           
                ->add('categories', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false, 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'label' => 'Chose your categories'))

            ->end();
```

Shows the following error:
Object of class Project\PortalBundle\Entity\Categories could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful for you.

Please change annotation of your both entities.

Entity **Portal**:

```
/** 
 * @var \Categories
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categories")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="portal_Categories",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="portal_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="cat_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $categories;
```

Entity **Categories**:

```
 /**
 * @var \Portal
 *  
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Portal", mappedBy="categories")
 */
private $portals;
```

And I try with this:

```
    $formMapper
       ->with('Portal')   
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => ' Name'))
            ->add('description', 'text', array('label' => 'Description'))
            ->add('webSiteLink', 'text', array('label' => 'Web Site ','required'=> false))           
            ->add('categories', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false, 'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'label' => 'Chose your categories'))

        ->end();
```

May be helpful